# How to use /deep/ in polymer with keyframes

Tags: polymer, dart-polymer, custom-element

I have 2 polymer components one parent and one child. because I know I will have to create more children, I would like to move my css code in the parent like that every child could use it. I stated moving my code and everything went fine until now with that code.

Old code

```dart
        .decale01 {
            -webkit-animation-name: decale;
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes decale {
            0% {
                top: 0;
            }
            100% {
                top: -40px;
            }
        }
```

new code

```dart
        :host /deep/ .decale {
            -webkit-animation-name: decale;
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes decale {
            0% {
                top: 0;
            }
            100% {
                top: -40px;
            }
        }
```

It seems that it does not work for animation or I have to do extra work for that to works ... any ideas ? other solution ? Cheers !

**Update**

I hosted some code on bitbucket [here](https://bitbucket.org/BenNG/polymer-dart-examples)

[on that commit](https://bitbucket.org/BenNG/polymer-dart-examples/commits/1d30455d195a6a058c6524a98e54f8b4d7c55d51) I created a child with is style. If you load the page you will see the animation

[on this one](https://bitbucket.org/BenNG/polymer-dart-examples/commits/698219cc5c349ce3f79b68e4bc30ea3d39597c8d) I put the child el in his parent and move the style code in the parent. The child act like he has no style

[and the last one](https://bitbucket.org/BenNG/polymer-dart-examples/commits/0860106942faceaa4c5f68aa28942fc6cc59852f) All style work except the animation

clone the repo and use 'pub get' and 'pub serve' to see the animation

Comment: humm I saw some examples with body /deep/ .my-class{...} I will try that...

Comment: Hey, Can you share your template code, so I can help you better?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `:host` can be used this way.

This should work.

```
    * /deep/ .decale {
        -webkit-animation-name: decale;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes decale {
        0% {
            top: 0;
        }
        100% {
            top: -40px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi I didn't try this one... it doesn't work though. happy new year ;)

Comment: What about `.decale01` without `* /deep/`?

Comment: No it does not work because of the shadow DOM. I need something that let me pass through it.

Comment: Your question doesn't show how you are using shadow DOM. Can you please add some code?

Comment: Your child element doesn't contain an element with class `decale01`. On which tag should this animation be applied?. Maybe I miss something, I haven't used CSS keyframe animation yet.

Comment: I also didn't find a tag with class `decale` in your child element so to what tag in your child element should the animation be applied?

Comment: It is not applied. you need to apply it to see the animation

Comment: Which tag should be animated. I can't see a tag in your child element that matches the selector `.decale`.

Comment: I used to add it live in my debugger tool to see the animation but it was not very clear... I modified the commits.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the selector like in my answer should work in this situation. Maybe a bug/limitation in Dartium with keyframe animations and shadow DOM.

Comment: That make sense for me too but no that does not work tested on dartium and chrome